# Palette Software

Tags: windows

I want a pallete software for development purposes. I want it to give out hexadecimal codes just so I can easily access it with ease. But other than that that's about it. Also I want it for windows operating system.

Here is the link to a online palette [HERE](http://paletton.com). I want it to be like that but can be accessed offline as I referred to before 'software'.

Comment: What do you mean with 'pallete software', 'development purposes', 'give out hexadecimal codes'?

Comment: @Chenmunka I've updated the post.

Comment: It's still not clear, but if I'm guessing right you're looking for a [color picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=color-picker+windows) – where you can click on the color and get its color-value displayed in hex for CSS, like `#ffffff` for plain white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install [python](http://python.org) and [wxPython](http://wxpython.org) **including the Documents & Demos package.**

Run the wxPython demo and Search on ColourDB - the result:

[2[image: ]]

- Free
- Just about any platform including Windows
- You can customise it
- Lots more.